# Excel macro - read data from array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

How do you read the data from a dynamic array out?

```
ReDim idx(1 To nItemsToPick)
ReDim varRandomItems(1 To nItemsToPick)
For i = 1 To nItemsToPick
    Do
        booIndexIsUnique = True
        idx(i) = Int(nItemsTotal * Rnd + 1)
        For j = 1 To i - 1
            If idx(i) = idx(j) Then
                booIndexIsUnique = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If booIndexIsUnique = True Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    varRandomItems(i) = rngList.Cells(idx(i), 1)
Next i
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where is your array coming from?

Comment: What do you mean Jonsca?

Comment: Is your array data on the same sheet? a different sheet? in a file? :)

Comment: ooh! it's on the same sheet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you have to get the user to input a starting cell and whether they want the data horizontally or vertically.

Then if the user inputs "A1", and there are 10 elements and the orientation is horizontal you need to turn that into a string -> "A1:A10"

```
Range("A1:J10") = varRandomItems
```

or

```
Range("A1:A10") = Application.Transpose(varRandomItems)
```

(apologies, I'm forgetting how to put the strings together at this point)